# How can I get 3 user mentions? - discord-js

Tags: discord.js

I'm doing a test command where the bot takes 3 mentions of users and then mentions them, however, the second user (user2) always returns `undefined`.
I've tried a few ways, but none of them work.

**What I got so far:**

```js
let user1 = message.mentions.users.first();
let user2 = message.mentions.users.find((i) => i == args[1]);
let user3 = message.mentions.users.last();

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("GREEN")
    .setDescription(`${user1} - ${user2} ${user3}`);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: View my answer in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034282/im-trying-to-create-a-ship-command-with-a-three-members-its-possible-i-tried/66034807#66034807)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are telling the code to find a mention within a mention, which is not possible. Why not just set `user2` to `args[1]`?

```
const user2 = args[0];
```

That should theoretically work.

Update: Yes, setting description to the args itself does return the mention, I just tested it:

```
const testEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(args[1]);
  message.channel.send(testEmbed);
```

Comment: As I didn't think about it '-', thank you @Kub_Luk

Comment: No problem, happy to help!